# Что означает template<class ErrorPolicy = class TErrorPolicy>?

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, что означает `class ErrorPolicy = class TErrorPolicy` в объявлении шаблона?

Наткнулся [здесь](https://github.com/boost-ext/di#quick-guide---bind-templates) в разделе про template.

Comment: Объявляется параметр шаблона `ErrorPolicy` со значением `TErrorPolicy` по-умолчанию.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, напишете в ответ?

Comment: Лучше закрыть вопрос - это же в любом учебнике написано...